# Problems with Graphics drawImage

Tags: java, swing, graphics, drawimage

I've been hunting through past StackOverflow posts and trying to figure out why my image won't display.

I know that the `ImageIO` is fine since I can run `getWidth()` on my `BufferedImage` and it returns the correct width.

Here is my `Graphic` class, followed by my main class. 
(I'm sorry for trashy code, I'm new to this.)

Code in `Graphic` class:

```
package blackjack;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Graphic extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game Window"); 
public JPanel layout = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
public JPanel menu = new JPanel();
public JPanel playing = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
public JPanel game = new JPanel();
public BufferedImage cardArray[] = new BufferedImage[52]; 
public void begin() {
    //starting menu
}


public void playersTurn() {
    menu.add(playing);

    Font font = new Font("",Font.PLAIN, 24);
    JPanel btnHolder = new JPanel();
    JLabel play = new JLabel("Playing:");
    JLabel or = new JLabel(" or ");
    JLabel question = new JLabel(" ? ");
    question.setFont(font);
    or.setFont(font);
    play.setFont(font);
    JButton hit = new JButton("Hit");
    JButton stand = new JButton("Stand");
    hit.addActionListener(this); 
    stand.addActionListener(this);


    playing.add(play, BorderLayout.WEST);
    playing.add(btnHolder, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    btnHolder.add(hit);
    btnHolder.add(or);
    btnHolder.add(stand);
    btnHolder.add(question);


}


public void gui() {
    //main gui


    Dimension imageD = new Dimension(71,96);
    Dimension menuD = new Dimension(900,120);
    menu.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    menu.setPreferredSize(menuD); 

    JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel title = new JLabel("BlackJack");
    title.setFont(new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    titlePanel.add(title);

    Graphic gr = new Graphic();
    gr.setPreferredSize(imageD);

    //adding
    frame.add(layout);
    layout.add(menu, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    layout.add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    layout.add(gr, BorderLayout.CENTER); 

    //frame settings
    frame.setSize(900, 650);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void buildPathArray() {

    for(int i = 1; i<=52; i++){
    BufferedImage im = null;
    try {
        im = ImageIO.read(new File(Blackjack.getInstallDir() + Blackjack.s + "src" + Blackjack.s + "cardpngs"+ Blackjack.s + (100+i)+".png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      cardArray[i-1]= im;
      //System.out.println(Blackjack.getInstallDir() + "\\src\\cardpngs\\" + (100+i)+".png");
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Hit")) {

    } else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Stand")) {

    }

}
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    //g.fillOval(20, 20, 20, 20);
    g.drawImage(cardArray[0], 0, 0, this); 
}

}
```

Code in my main class:

```
package blackjack;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Blackjack {
public static String installDir = ""; 
public static String s = ""; 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
    installDir = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
    s = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    Graphic gr = new Graphic();
    gr.buildPathArray();
    gr.gui();
    //System.out.println(installDir);
    //g.playersTurn();

}
public static String getInstallDir() {
    return installDir; 
}

}
```

The output is this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You're creating one instance of `Graphic` in your `Blackjack` class...

```
public class Blackjack {
    public static String installDir = ""; 
    public static String s = ""; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //...
        Graphic gr = new Graphic();
        gr.buildPathArray();
        gr.gui();
    }
```

And another in your `Graphic` class

```
public void gui() {
    //...
    Graphic gr = new Graphic();
    gr.setPreferredSize(imageD);

    //adding
       //...
    layout.add(gr, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
    //...
}
```

But you only initialise the images, using `buildPathArray` of the instance in you `BlackBelt` class, which is not what is actually displayed on the screen...

As a general rule of thumb, you shouldn't be creating an instance of `JFrame` from within another component with the express purpose of display that component.  Your `Graphic` component is also trying to do too much.  Instead, I would have a `Game` class, maybe, which pulled the title, menu and `Graphic` components together and then put that onto an instance of `JFrame`

The main reason for this is, is your `Graphic` class is trying to do too much.  It should be solely responsible for display the cards and managing them. The `Game` class should manage the other UI elements and be responsible for ensuring that the UI meets the current state of the game "model", taking in user input (and listening to events from the other UI elements) and updating the model and responding to events that the model creates, a little more like...

## `BlackJack`...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class BlackJack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BlackJack();
    }

    public BlackJack() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new Game());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Game extends JPanel {

        private JPanel menu;
        private Graphic graphic;

        public Game() {

            menu = new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(900, 120);
                }
            };
            menu.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

            JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
            JLabel title = new JLabel("BlackJack");
            title.setFont(new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 14));
            titlePanel.add(title);

            Graphic gr = new Graphic();
            gr.buildPathArray();

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            add(menu, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(gr, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

    }

}
```

## `Graphic`...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Graphic extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public BufferedImage cardArray[] = new BufferedImage[52];

    public void begin() {
        //starting menu
    }

    public void playersTurn() {
        // All of this belongs in Game
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(71,96);
    }

    public void buildPathArray() {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 52; i++) {
            BufferedImage im = null;
            try {
                im = ImageIO.read(new File(Blackjack.getInstallDir() + Blackjack.s + "src" + Blackjack.s + "cardpngs" + Blackjack.s + (100 + i) + ".png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            cardArray[i - 1] = im;
            //System.out.println(Blackjack.getInstallDir() + "\\src\\cardpngs\\" + (100+i)+".png");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        //g.fillOval(20, 20, 20, 20);
        g.drawImage(cardArray[0], 0, 0, this);
    }

}
```

You might also want to have a look at [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).